# Connecting Rasa to a database to store responses

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, rasa, rasa-nlu

I'm trying to connect my rasa open source chatbot to a local database and store response from the user. But I couldn't succeed in the process of integrating database to my chatbot. I tried using google but nothing seems to be working. I hope I'll get a solution from community members. Attaching the data for your reference.

**nlu.yml**

```
nlu:

- intent: painting_request


examples: |
    - im interested in buying a painting
    - i'm interested in buying a painting
    - I'm interested in buying a painting
    - interested in buying canvas
    - id like to request a painting
    - id like to buy a painting
    - im looking for a painting that have a beautuful background
    - i would like to get a sketch of my photograph
    - i would like to get a sketch of my photo

- intent: art_type_entry
  examples: |
    - im looking for a [graphite](art_type) painting 
    - i'm looking for a [graphite](art_type) sketch
    - i want to buy a [graphite](art_type) painting
    - i want to buy a [graphite](art_type) sketch
    - can i able to get a [graphite](art_type) art
    - i want my picture to be drawn in [graphite](art_type)
    - im looking for a [charcoal](art_type) painting 
    - i'm looking for a [charcoal](art_type) sketch
    - i want to buy a [charcoal](art_type) painting
    - i want to buy a [charcoal](art_type) sketch
    - can i able to get a [charcoal](art_type) art
    - i want my picture to be drawn in [charcoal](art_type)
    - im looking for a [coloured pencil art](art_type) painting 
    - i'm looking for a [coloured pencil art](art_type) sketch
    - i want to buy a [coloured pencil art](art_type) painting
    - i want to buy a [coloured pencil art](art_type) sketch
    - can i able to get a [coloured pencil art](art_type) art
    - i want my picture to be drawn in [coloured pencil art](art_type)
    - i want my picture to be drawn in [oil painting](art_type)
    - im looking for a [oil painting](art_type) painting 
    - i'm looking for a [oil painting](art_type) sketch
    - i want to buy a [oil painting](art_type) painting
    - i want to buy a [oil painting](art_type) sketch
    - can i able to get a [oil painting](art_type) art
    - i want my picture to be drawn in [oil painting](art_type)
    
- intent: size_entry
  examples: |
    - size should be of [a4](size)
    - size should be of [a3](size)
    - size should be of [a2](size)
    - size should be of [a1](size)
    - painting should be of [a4](size)
    - painting should be of [a3](size)
    - painting should be of [a2](size)
    - painting should be of [a1](size)

- intent: frame_entry
  examples: |
    - my frame should be of [standard](frame)
    - my frame should be of [wooden](frame)
    - my frame should be of [designer](frame)
    - my canvas should be fitted with a [standard](frame)
    - my canvas should be fitted with a [wooden](frame)
    - my canvas should be fitted with a [designer](frame)
    - frame should be of [standard](frame)
    - frame should be of [Wooden](frame)
    - frame should be of [designer](frame)

- intent: finishing_entry
  examples: |
    - the outer finishing should be done with [maple](finishing)
    - the outer finishing should be done with [walnut](finishing)
    - the outer finishing should be done with [black](finishing)
    - the outer finishing should be done with [white](finishing)
    - the outer finishing should be done with [glass](finishing)
    - outer finishing should be done with [brass](finishing)
    - outer finishing should be done with [maple](finishing)
    - outer finishing should be done with [walnut](finishing)
    - outer finishing should be done with [black](finishing)
    - outer finishing should be done with [white](finishing)
    - outer finishing should be done with [glass](finishing)
    - outer finishing should be done with [brass](finishing)

- intent: orientation_entry
  examples: |
    - orientation of canvas should be in [landscape](orientation)
    - orientation of canvas should be in [potrait](orientation)
    - orientation of canvas should be in [designer choice](orientation)
```

**rules.yml**

```
rules:


- rule: activate painting form
    steps:
    - intent: painting_request
    - action: painting_form
    - active_loop: painting_form

  - rule: submit form
    condition:
    - active_loop: painting_form
    steps:
    - action: painting_form
    - active_loop: null
    - action: utter_submit
    - action: utter_slots_values
```

**stories.yml**

```
stories:


- story: confirmation
    steps:
    - intent: affirm
    - action: utter_affirm

  - story: stop form + continue
    steps:
      - intent: painting_request
      - action: painting_form
      - active_loop: painting_form
      - intent: out_of_scope
      - action: utter_ask_continue
      - intent: affirm
      - action: painting_form
      - active_loop: null
      - action: utter_submit
      - action: utter_slots_values

  - story: stop form + stop
    steps:
      - intent: painting_request
      - action: painting_form
      - active_loop: painting_form
      - intent: out_of_scope
      - action: utter_ask_continue
      - intent: deny
      - action: action_deactivate_loop
      - active_loop: null
```

**domain.yml**

```
intents:


- greet
  - goodbye
  - affirm
  - reject
  - mood_great
  - mood_unhappy
  - bot_challenge
  - askname
  - help
  - out_of_scope
  - art_type_entry
  - size_entry
  - frame_entry
  - finishing_entry
  - orientation_entry
  - painting_request:
      use_entities: []

entities:
  - art_type
  - size
  - frame
  - finishing
  - orientation

actions:
- validate_painting_form # From actions.py page

slots:
  model:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    auto_fill: false
  frame_size:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    auto_fill: false
  frame_type:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    auto_fill: false
  frame_orientation:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    auto_fill: false
  frame_finishing:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false
    auto_fill: false
  requested_slot:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: false

forms:
  painting_form:
    required_slots:
      model:
      - type: from_entity
        entity: art_type
      frame_size:
      - type: from_entity
        entity: size
      frame_type:
      - type: from_entity
        entity: frame
      frame_orientation:
      - type: from_entity
        entity: orientation
      frame_finishing:
      - type: from_entity
        entity: finishing

responses:
  utter_greet:
  - text: "Hey! Welcome to My Website, how can I help you?  "
  - text: "Hi Welcome to My Website, how can I help you?"

  utter_reject:
  - text: "Sorry to hear it,How can I help you?"
  - text: "Did that help you?"

  utter_default:
  - text: "I am not sure what you're aiming for."
  - text: "I am sorry but I am not able to get you."
  - text: "My appologies but I am not able to get you."  

  utter_happy:
  - text: "Great, carry on!"

  utter_cheer_up:
  - text: "Sorry to hear that."

  utter_affirm:
  - text: "Nice to hear it"

  utter_goodbye:
  - text: "Bye"

  utter_name:
  - text: "I am a bot, powered by Rasa."

  utter_bot_help:
  - text: "I'm here to help you in customising your painting."
  - text: "I'm powered by A.I here to helps you in guide to buy a beautiful painting with your desired customisation."
  - text: "I'm here to gather information of how you want your painting to be."
  
  utter_ask_continue:
  - text: "Do you want to continue?"
  
  utter_wrong_art_type:
  - text: "Sorry we are unable to proceed with your art type, please try again"

  utter_wrong_size_type:
  - text: "Sorry we are unable to proceed with your size type, please try again"

  utter_wrong_frame_type:
  - text: "Sorry we are unable to proceed with your frame type, please try again"

  utter_wrong_finishing_type:
  - text: "Sorry we are unable to proceed with your finishing type, please try again"

  utter_wrong_orientation_type:
  - text: "Sorry we are unable to proceed with your orientation type, please try again"
  
  utter_ask_model:
  - text: "What is your desired art model"
  
  utter_ask_frame_size:
  - text: "Please enter your required size"
  
  utter_ask_frame_type:
  - text: "Please enter your desired frame type"
  
  utter_ask_frame_finishing:
  - text: "Please enter your deisired finishing"
  
  utter_ask_frame_orientation:
  - text: "Please enter orientation"
  
  utter_submit:
  - text: "Thanks for the information provided."

  utter_slots_values:
  - text: "I am going to run a search using the following parameters:\n
            - art_type: {model}\n
            - size: {frame_size}\n
            - frame: {frame_type}\n
            - finishing: {frame_finishing}\n
            - orientation: {frame_orientation}"


session_config:
  session_expiration_time: 60
  carry_over_slots_to_new_session: true
```

**actions.py**

```
from database_connector import DataUpdate
from typing import Any, Text, Dict, List, Union

from rasa_sdk import Tracker 
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
from rasa_sdk.forms import FormValidationAction

class PaintingFormValidation(FormValidationAction):

    """Example of a form validation action."""

    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "validate_painting_form"

    def slot_mappings(self) -> Dict[Text, Union[Dict, List[Dict]]]:
        return{
            "model": [self.from_entity(entity='art_type', intent='art_type_entry')],
            "frame_size": [self.from_entity(entity='size', intent='size_entry')],
            "frame_type": [self.from_entity(entity='frame', intent='frame_entry')],
            "frame_finishing": [self.from_entity(entity='finishing', intent='finishing_entry')],
            "frame_orientation": [self.from_entity(entity='orientation', intent='orientation_entry')]
        }

    @staticmethod
    def art_type_db() -> List[Text]:
        """Database of supported cuisines."""

        return [
            "graphite",
            "charcoal",
            "sketching",
            "oilPainting",
            "colored pencil"
        ]

    @staticmethod
    def size_db() -> List[Text]:
        """Database of supported sizes"""

        return [
            "a1",
            "a2",
            "a3",
            "a4"
        ]

    @staticmethod
    def frame_db() -> List[Text]:
        """Database of supported frame types"""

        return [
            "no frame",
            "standard",
            "designer"
            ]

    @staticmethod
    def finishing_db() -> List[Text]:
        """Database of supported finishing"""

        return [
            "maple",
            "wood",
            "metal",
            "glass",
            "walnut"
        ]

    @staticmethod
    def orientation_db() -> List[Text]:
        """Database of supported orientations."""

        return [
            "landscape",
            "potrait",
            "designer choice"
            ]

    @staticmethod
    def is_int(string: Text) -> bool:
        """Check if a string is an integer."""

        try:
            int(string)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def validate_model(
        self,
        value: Text,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any],
    ) -> Dict[Text, Any]:
        """Validate art type value."""

        if value.lower() in self.art_type_db():
            # validation succeeded, set the value of the "art_type" slot to value
            return {"model": value}
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_wrong_art_type")
            # validation failed, set this slot to None, meaning the
            # user will be asked for the slot again
            return {"model": None}

    def validate_frame_size(
        self,
        value: Text,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any],
    ) -> Dict[Text, Any]:
        """Validate size value."""

        if value.lower() in self.size_db():
            # validation succeeded, set the value of the "size" slot to value
            return {"frame_size": value}
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_wrong_size_type")
            # validation failed, set this slot to None, meaning the
            # user will be asked for the slot again
            return {"frame_size": None}

    def validate_frame_type(
        self,
        value: Text,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any],
    ) -> Dict[Text, Any]:
        """Validate frame type value."""

        if value.lower() in self.frame_db():
            # validation succeeded, set the value of the "frame" slot to value
            return {"frame_type": value}
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_wrong_frame_type")
            # validation failed, set this slot to None, meaning the
            # user will be asked for the slot again
            return {"frame_type": None}

    def validate_frame_finishing(
        self,
        value: Text,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any],
    ) -> Dict[Text, Any]:
        """Validate finishing value."""

        if value.lower() in self.finishing_db():
            # validation succeeded, set the value of the "finishing" slot to value
            return {"frame_finishing": value}
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_wrong_finishing_type")
            # validation failed, set this slot to None, meaning the
            # user will be asked for the slot again
            return {"frame_finishing": None}

    def validate_frame_orientation(
        self,
        value: Text,
        dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any],
    ) -> Dict[Text, Any]:
        """Validate orientation value."""

        if value.lower() in self.orientation_db():
            # validation succeeded, set the value of the "orientation" slot to value
            return {"frame_orientation": value}
        else:
            dispatcher.utter_message(response="utter_wrong_orientation_type")
            # validation failed, set this slot to None, meaning the
            # user will be asked for the slot again
            return {"frame_orientation": None}

    def submit(
        self,
        dispatcher:CollectingDispatcher,
        tracker: Tracker,
        domain: Dict[Text, Any]
     ) -> List[Dict]:

        dispatcher.utter_message(template="utter_submit")

        DataUpdate(tracker.get_slot("model"), tracker.get_slot("frame_size"), tracker.get_slot("frame_type"), tracker.get_slot("frame_finishing"), tracker.get_slot("frame_orientation"))
        dispatcher.utter_message("Your response has been loaded.")
        
        return []
```

**database_connector.py**

```
import psycopg2

def DataUpdate(art_type_entry, size_entry, frame_entry, finishing_entry, orientation_entry):
    '''
    Pushes Descriptive Analytics Data to the Database
    '''
    db = psycopg2.connect(
                host="localhost",
                database="Rasa_Chatbot",
                user="postgres",
                password="postgres"
                )

    mycursor = db.connect()
    
    postgres_insert_query = """INSERT INTO rasainfo(model,size,type,orientation,finishing) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s);""".format(art_type_entry,size_entry, frame_entry, finishing_entry, orientation_entry)
    
    mycursor.execute(postgres_insert_query)
    
    db.commit()

    print("Record inserted successfully into table")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this in your endpoints.yml

```
  tracker_store:
  type: SQL
  dialect: "postgresql"  # the dialect used to interact with the db
  url: "postgres"
  db: "rasa"  # path to your db
  username:  # username used for authentication
  password:  # password used for authentication
  query: # optional dictionary to be added as a query string to the connection URL
    driver: my-driver
```